# Visual Studio Installer "Setup Project" Have a .js run after install and then another before uninstall?

Tags: javascript, c#, command-line, installation, setup-project

I have this program where a server is made. Before the server can start though I need to register it. This is a one time thing as re-registering it will change all the dcom data and settings to factory settings. Which I don't want. So What I have set up is a JS file that runs my program and gives it a parameter argument "register" which is handled in my program to register the server. Similarly before uninstalling I want to run a similar JS file that passes an unregister argument so the server is no longer listed on client views after it's been removed. To be clear I have both of these JS files working fine and they successfully register/unregister my server as needed.

My issue is that I've added these files in the application directory and in my Visual studio installer: Setup Project, I have gone to right click installer project > view > custom actions. Then I right clicked the install folder and added my regserver.JS file and similarly for uninstall I've added my unregserver.JS file. The problem lays in the order that these get run. When the intaller runs it first run my regserver.JS. This is bad because there is no .exe of my program existing yet so an error is thrown... Is there a way to specify in my project that this JS is only to be executed AFTER the installation finishes?

Or is there a clever wrap around to this? Maybe I'm doing it all wrong!

EDIT: ..just an idea... what if I make ANOTHER two JS files that delay for like 30 seconds while the installer runs and then they execute my regserver/unregserver files... Really sloppy but I mean it might work...

Comment: All Visual Studio custom actions run after all the files are installed, So the question is really about why your exe doesn't work, and that would be a better question to ask, saying exactly what your custom action does, how it finds the .js file, or however you do the registration.